# Configurar WebService

Tags: jsf, web-service

Estou com dificuldades para configurar um método POST, estou implementando a integração com a plataforma de pagamentos Gerencianet, o suporte deles me retornou a seguinte mensagem em um chamado:

> Prezado, tente por gentileza avalie o cabeçalho do seu arquivo de consulta ao token. Como não conhecemos os seus arquivos de implementação, além do fato de não podermos interferir por questões de segurança, vou tentar auxiliá-lo para buscarmos uma solução apropriada.

Eu acredito que o erro refere-se a chamada não incluir a instrução "Content-Type: application/json". http://prntscr.com/e2megi

HTTP 415 significa que o servidor não entende o formato de mídia da solicitação. No seu controlador você está especificando que aceita JSON, mas você não disse se o pedido indicou que o corpo está nesse formato. Só porque você colocou os dados em formato JSON, não significa que o servidor vai reconhecê-lo, você tem que indicá-lo no Content-Type header.

```
/**
 * Método que recebe o Token do Gerencianet via POST
 * 
 * Então é passado para o método que realiza a consulta via Token
 * e atualiza o Objeto no BD
 * */
@POST
@Path("/RecebeToken")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public void recebeToken(String token){
    System.out.println("Token Recebido: "+token);
    //CheckOut.consultar(token);

}
```

Comment: A questão me pareceu confusa e não a entendi muito bem. De qualquer forma esta estranho o fato de apesar de a nomenclatura CONSUMES especificar que o a função irá receber um objeto JSON a função em si recebe uma STRING. A função recebeToken deveria  estar declarada assim: public void recebeToken(  JSONObject token )

Comment: Bem, fiz como sugeriu, ficou da seguinte forma:

@POST
@Path("/RecebeToken")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public void recebeToken(JSONObject token){
Porém obtive o mesmo erro.

Bem, o contexto é o seguinte. Eu gero um boleto para pagamento nessa plataforma (Gerencianet) e para eu não ficar "consultando" a situação do Boleto eles fazem um "POST" em meu webservice quando o status do Boleto é alterado me passando esse token, então somente ai eu faço uma consulta e vejo o que houve de alteração.

Comment: Primeiro você tem que saber, qual a especificação do webservice que vai consumir e depois fazer seu client conforme a especificação, fiz uma integração de pagamentos em novembro, optei pelo iugu, porque nenhum dos mais famosos no mercado tinha documentação apropriada para fazer a integração, mesmo com a documentação é penoso, porque a maioria das implementações não seguem a especificação a risca, isso gera problemas e conflitos